# for loop: dataframe * vector operation

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to make some operations on my dataframe by multiplying cells value to a vector.

```r
mydat <- dataframe(
type = rep("a", "b", "c", "d"),
site.a = c(10, 2.5,5,4),
site.b = c(6, 3, 7, 3.1),
site.c = c(2, 2.4, 6, 7),
site.d = c(9, 6, 7.2, 4.2))
```

I would like to multiply each column in order by the following vector

```r
wall <- c(10.4, 11, 12, 13.5)
```

i.e I would like to have a for loop for the following:
`mydat[2]*wall[1]`,
`site.b*wall[2]`,
etc... until `mydat[n+1]*wall[n]`

I tried to following code but I doesn't work, It said the following error `"unexpected "{" in "}"`

```r
while (i < 8) {
  for i in (1:8) {
    mydat[i+1] = mydat[i+1]/wall[i]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me? I am just beginning how to code and I am not familiar with looping

Comment: (1) It's `for (i in 1:8) { ... }`. (2) Why are you using a `while` and a `for` loop? They both use the same index variable, this won't work. (3) Are you looking for something like `mydat[,-1] <- mydat[,-1] * wall`? (4) Since `mydat` is a data.frame, you need two indizes or at least something like `mydat[, i+1]`.

Comment: It would be safer to not overwrite the original data. Something like mydat2 <- mydat and then mydat2[, -1] <- mydat[, -1] * wall so that the new data is in mydat2 but the original data is preserved in `mydat`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. The answer is actually shorter that I thought.

```r
for (i in 1:4){
  mydat2[,i+1] <-  mydat[,i+1]/wall[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider no loops with matrix operations by expanding the `wall` vector to matrix of same size as `mydat`. Below assumes columns will be same between both objects:

```r
wall_m <- matrix(wall, ncol=length(wall), nrow=nrow(mydat), byrow=TRUE)

mydat2[-1] <- mydat2[-1] / wall_m
```

---

Above approach yields identical results:

```r
mydat <- data.frame(
  type = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  site.a = c(10, 2.5,5,4),
  site.b = c(6, 3, 7, 3.1),
  site.c = c(2, 2.4, 6, 7),
  site.d = c(9, 6, 7.2, 4.2)
)
mydat2 <- mydat

wall <- c(10.4, 11, 12, 13.5)

# LOOP VERSION
for(i in (1:4)) {
  mydat[i+1] = mydat[i+1]/wall[i]
}

# MATRIX VERSION
wall_m <- matrix(wall, ncol=length(wall), nrow=nrow(mydat2), byrow=TRUE)
mydat2[-1] <- mydat2[-1] / wall_m

identical(mydat, mydat2)
[1] TRUE
```